# Sql linq query with where and group by

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

Iam having a serious problems with Linq. I have simple sql query:

```
 select 
    intMiesiac, 
    intRok, 
    Sum(intIn) as 'In',
    Sum(intOut) as 'Out' 
from dbo.GlobalDane 
where intRampNr=1 
group by intMiesiac, intRok
```

I query for sum of in and out for specified intRampNr and want it to be grouped by Month and Year.
Tried very various queries in linq but when i put result of query into datasource of gridview and then bind datasource it fails or it shows me only empty cells.
How I can create same statment in linq under C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following will do it for you:

```
var results = 
    dataContext.GlobalDanes
    .Where(gd => gd.intRampNr == 1)
    .GroupBy(
        gd =>
            new 
            {
                 gd.intMiesiac,
                 gd.intRok,
            })
    .Select(
        grp =>
            new 
            {
                grp.Key.intMiesiac,
                grp.Key.intRok,
                In = grp.Sum(gd => gd.intIn),
                Out = grp.Sum(gd => gd.inOut),
            });
```

Comment: ah thanks my queries were good but my binding code with evals were wrong thats why couldnt bind it property. Also thax for query it looks better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Also in query syntax

```
from a in db.GlobalDane
where a.intRampNr == 1 
group a by new { a.intMiesiac, a.intRok, } into g 
select new 
{ 
    g.Key.intMiesiac,
    g.Key.intRok, 
    In = g.Sum(X => X.intIn),
    Out = g.Sum(X => X.inOut),
};
```